# What is copying profile in account tab?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Needs clarification. "Don't make me think."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the profile copies things like your *name*, *email*, *location*, *about me* to the current profile.  It doesn't copy your reputation, interesting tags, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It copies the profile from the other site. What exactly don't you understand?